# Can‘t get modified value by attr() when updated using data()

Tags: jquery

*HTML*

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="btn-link link-primary ml10 js-lock" data-val="1">loc</a>
```

*Script*

```
$(".js-lock").click(function(e) {
    console.info($(this).attr("data-val"));
    console.info($(this).data("val"));
    $(this).data("val", "0");
})
```

now click, console output:

> 1
>
> 1

now click again, console output:

> 1
>
> 0

another situation

*HTML*

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="btn-link link-primary ml10 js-lock" data-val="1">lock</a>
```

*Script*

```
$(".js-lock").click(function(e) {
    console.info($(this).attr("data-val"));
    console.info($(this).data("val"));
    $(this).attr("data-val", "0");
})
```

now click, console output:

> 1
>
> 1

now click again, console output:

> 0
>
> 1

someone can tell me why???

Answer (score 0):

Since [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) uses internal cache it only uses uses the data attribute as the default value only. On performing update operation via `.data(key, value)` then DOM is not updated.

If you use [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get and set, you will get the updated value. What you **shouldn't** use, is a mix of [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) and [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/). And if you have no real reason to update the attribute, then use [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) to get and set value.